# Convert Scatter to Contour, every dot turns into a highland

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, interpolation

How to build a Contour plot (specifically, topographic map) based on a Scatter plot, so that every scatter dot is converted into a **circular area being the highest one in a given radius**, i.e., any adjoining area is lower than the original dot’s area?

On the exemplary image, the yellow adjoining area is lower than the highland #6. Note, I am not trying to build a data density plot.

[image: Exemplary image]

All input scatter dots are higher than the green grass level.

I tried to interpolate the x, y, and z coordinates using matplotlib’s griddata as proposed in question [Make contour of scatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18764814/make-contour-of-scatter).
On the second figure you see the original superimposed scatter plot and contour plot generated after interpolation. However, the dot #6 is not the highest one like it is on the first image, and the snow-capped mountain is shifted from the original white dot #1.

[image: Superimposed Scatter and wrong Contour plots]

Here are my coordinates:

```
x = [34, 74, 34, 70, 4, 42, 10, 56, 50, 0, 15, 104, 53, 27]
y = [44, 52, 21, 25, 34, 54, 70, 77, 0, 50, 5, 53, 18, 86]
z = [0.9, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6]
```

Any ideas are highly appreciated.

Comment: Not 100% sure but a  [kernel density estimator](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html) might do what you want.

Comment: Not really a programming question.  Maybe try [stats.se]

Comment: It looks like the coordinates are somehow shifted. In order to find out the reason you need to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `bivariate_normal` function to get elevation for each point. Here is the working code to try:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab

# data
x = np.array([34, 74, 34, 70, 4, 42, 10, 56, 50, 0, 15, 104, 53, 27])
y = np.array([44, 52, 21, 25, 34, 54, 70, 77, 0, 50, 5, 53, 18, 86])
z = np.array([0.9, 0.8, 0.8, 0.9, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6])

# the radius that needs to specified for each point
# radius = sigmax=sigmay for bivariate_normal
#rad = [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7]  # OK
rad = [4, 6, 7, 3, 5, 5, 7, 6, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7]   # better

# get limits of plot
xmin, xmax = x.min(), x.max()
ymin, ymax = y.min(), y.max()

# some settings
delta = 0.5

# create mesh grid for plotting area
xs = np.arange(xmin-delta, xmax+delta*2, delta)
ys = np.arange(ymin-delta, ymax+delta*2, delta)
XX, YY = np.meshgrid(xs, ys)

# compute elevation Z for each point in the grid mesh
ZZ=0
for mx, my, mz, mr in zip(x, y, z, rad):
    sigmax = mr
    sigmay = mr
    vm = mlab.bivariate_normal(0, 0, sigmax, sigmay, 0, 0)  # max value

    # mz and vm are used to correct the elevation obtained from bivar-normal
    ZZ += mlab.bivariate_normal(XX, YY, sigmax, sigmay, mx, my) * mz / vm

# prep fig, ax
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9, 9))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

# choose cmap as you need
ctf=plt.contourf(XX, YY, ZZ, linewidth=1, cmap=cm.gist_earth_r)
plt.scatter(x, y, s=rad, color='r', zorder=10)

plt.xlim(xmin-delta, xmax+delta)
plt.ylim(ymin-delta, ymax+delta)

plt.colorbar(ctf)
plt.show()
```

The resulting plot:

[image]

Comment: I used `cmap=cm.terrain` - just to keep consistency with the chosen color map. Greatly appreciated!